# MVC Index default parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am still learning MVC so this is probably a very basic question but I am stumped...

An external company coded this application for us and I am making minor modification but I can't find where the parameter is set.

This is the Index action below, there is no Index() action so this is the default ActionResult.

Where would the viewRequest that is being supplied be being set?

I can reach this page by /Request/Index with no querystring.

I looked at the route mapping and I can't find anything.

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(ViewRequest viewRequest)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose ViewRequest object is just a list of primitive fields? In this case MVC execute autobinding of query string or post data params to the object before execute the action. Can you post ViewRequest structure?

Comment: It is a view model with 4 fields.

Comment: If these fields are primitive, as I says before, they will be automatically setted to query string/post data params. This is way you are not able to see where the parameter is set

Comment: I have copied the index page and renamed it to index2. Added [HttpGet] public ActionResult Index2(ViewRequest viewRequest) but it fails, looking for Index2() actionresult. Yes, I'm clearly clueless (sorry) but how can teh viewRequest be set for the Index but not Index2 when it is just a copy?

Comment: Code, code, *code*. Post your action, your RouteConfig.cs, view, etc. Anything that is relevant to the issue at hand. We can't tell you anything with just the action signature other than, it must not match. Why or how? Who knows?